# Determinant of matrix formed by all scaled combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, geometry, determinant, multilinear-algebra

**Question**

- $S$ is a $2^{n} \times n$ matrix where the rows are binary representations of 0 to $2^{n} - 1$.

  For $n = 2$,

$$S = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

- $\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}x_{1} & x_{2}& \ldots & x_{n}\end{bmatrix}$ is a real vector with elements in interval $(0, 1)$
- $A$ is a $2^{n} \times n$ matrix where

  $$A_{ij} = 
  \begin{cases} 
  1/x_j & \text{if } S_{ij} = 0 \\
  1/(1 - x_j) & \text{if } S_{ij} = 1 \\
  \end{cases}$$

What is $s_{n} = \det(A^{\intercal}A)$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C=A^tA$ then
$$C_{ii}=2^{n-1}\left(\frac1{x_i^2}+\frac1{(1-x_i)^2}\right)\\
C_{ij}=2^{n-2}\left(\frac1{x_i}+\frac1{1-x_i}\right)\left(\frac1{x_j}+\frac1{1-x_j}\right)$$
So $C$ is the sum of a diagonal matrix and a rank-1 matrix.

Comment: Divide $i^{th}$ row by $\sqrt{2^{n-2}}\left[x_{i}^{-1} + (1-x_{i})^{-1} \right]$. Same for column. Subtract every row by the 1st row, except for the 1st row. That yields a triangular matrix. Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

Comment: Ah, that rings a bell from undergrad.  I would have set up a recursion that I expected to match your formulae for small $n$.

Comment: My formulae for small $n$ are wrong because I have a typo in the question. For my actual problem,  $A_{ij}=-1/(1-x_{j})$ for $S_{ij}=1$ and $A_{ij}=1/x_{j}$ for $S_{ij}=0$. The same method works well anyway, after scaling the rows and column.